# Nginx How can I shorten the code?

Tags: nginx

My nginx configuration:

```
location ~(\d*?)-(\d*?).news.html{
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller/news.php?id=$2&count=$3;
}

location ~/(\d*?)-(\d*?).journal.html {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller/journal.php?id=$1&count=$2;
}

location ~/(\d*?)-(\d*?).event.html{
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller/event.php?id=$1&count=$2;
}

location ~ /news.php$ {
    fastcgi_cache my_cache;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;

    #cache for 2 hours
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 2h;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /journal.php$ {
    fastcgi_cache my_cache;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;

    #cache for 1 day
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1d;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /event.php$ {
    fastcgi_cache my_cache;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;

    #cache for 5 hours
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 5h;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I have three (or more) `locations` with html url redirected to corresponding php script, and with different `fastcgi_cache_valid` time.

So that I need to add totally six `location routes` to handle such logic. But at the bottom, a `php location route` without caching is needed for other php scripts.

However, all `php location route` have the nearly same attributes. How can it be shared among all `php location route`? Or is there any other shorter way to achieve the same mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you at least can move this code to external file

```
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
```

and replace it by something like...

```
include /path/to/php4fpm-nginx-fastcgi.conf;
```

Location parsing also looks replaceable

```
location ~(\d*?)-(\d*?).news.html{
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller/news.php?id=$2&count=$3;
}

location ~/(\d*?)-(\d*?).journal.html {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller/journal.php?id=$1&count=$2;
}

location ~/(\d*?)-(\d*?).event.html{
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller/event.php?id=$1&count=$2;
}
```

with

```
location ~(\d*?)-(\d*?).(news|journal|event).html{
    # note it has changed order for vars.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller/$3.php?id=$1&count=$2;
}
```

I would go even deeper and use `set $var "value"` in conditions and then reuse code, but let it be your homework.